# Celery-Django, Start and stop reminder emails for survey

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to implement a recurring daily reminder email task into my program that begins at a specific date/time and is stopped only when the customer completes the required action.

Is this something that is possible with Celery and Django? I've already found a way to send a one time task email via ETA- though am unsure how to set up a recurring event that can then be cancelled.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send emails on a daily basis, Celery provides a scheduler for recurring task named Celery beat:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Once you have Celery beat set up, create a task to send the emails based on user information. The task could look through all users and include only recipients that have a `send email` flag or a `datetime` information for sending the next email.

If the user completes the required action, you would unset the `send email` flag or delete the `datetime` information and the recurring task would stop sending emails to this user.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into celery beat a bit more!

Comment: After reading a bit more- and reading your solution a bit more thoroughly- i see a way to start an overall recurring task- but is there a way with Celery beat to start a "Beat" or recurring task at a specific ETA and then at a later date kill that Beat?

Comment: The celery beat recurring task should be general, i.e. not specific to a user. It should run all the time, e.g. every minute and collect emails to send based on the information saved with the users.

For example, it would see that User A should receive an email, because it is 9:20am, send the email and update the time for sending the next email to this user. If User A completes the required action, just delete the time for sending the next email.